# Can I export Collections out of Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have shopify and I want to be able to export my collections that show in a CSV my categories and sub categories and product titles. Can I do that?

Cannot figure out a way and am hoping for a file I can use as a reference of category structure as I inherited this site.

Answer (score 0):

Collections are a resource like any other in Shopify. At the very least, you can generate a list of all your collections and their specific criteria using API calls. Whether Shopify gives you a nice export is another matter. Anyway, it can be done without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

By default shopify doesn't allow us to export collection data in CSV format. We can export products but not collections.